# Passing a dictionary as a function parameter and calling the function in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

In the following code, how do I pass the dictionary to `func2`. How should `func2` be called?

```
def func2(a,**c):
 if len(c) > 0:
   print len(c)
   print c

u={'a':1,'b':2}
func2(1,u)
```

Comment: Your `for` loop still won't work. Get rid of the `and 'a' in c` and it would, not sure what that clause is trying to do?

Comment: @agf:i haqve modified the code ,now am just printing c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't run, because there are multiple parameters for the name a.

But if you change it to:

```
def func2(x,**c):
    if len(c) > 0:
    print len(c)
        print c
```

Then you call it as:

```
func2(1, a=1, b=2)
```

or

```
u={'a':1,'b':2}
func2(1, **u)
```

Comment: ya true i realized and have updated in of the comment.so parameters names and the dict key are not suppose to be the same.Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Just as it accepts them:

```
func2(1,**u)
```

Comment: additionally: `def func2(a,c): ...` and `func2(1,u)` would also work. using variable arguments or standard arguments depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: func2(1,**u) i get an error saying Typeerror:func2() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'

Comment: I got the above error because dictionary had the key 'a' and one of the parameters was also 'a'. when i changed it the error got resolved..

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
 def fun(*a, **kw):
     print a, kw

 a=[1,2,3]
 b=dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)

 fun(*a)
 fun(**kw)
 fun(*a, **kw)
```